# Map with comparable key types

Tags: c++, graph, typing

Lately I started working on the implementation of a graph based database system. However I ran into a little problem.

The vertices in the graph are allowed to contain properties, of any type of comparable type. I was thinking about creating a map for these, as the keys are always string based. However I don't want to be bothered at all by the actually type, the only thing I want to do is compare them and still maintain safety checks. How would I go around doing so?

As I first approach I was thinking about using boost, however it'll still give me the headache of doing some manual type checking, which I absolutely do not want to do.

In Java I would do something like this, however I'm not used with these kind of things in C++.

```
map<String, ? extends comparable>
```

The reason for this is that a property can literally be any comparable type.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do all your properties derive from some common base class? Have you considered `boost::any`? Or some sort of flexible JSON object instead of a `map`?

Comment: You just compare them in your template code. The compiler will yell at the user of your template who would try to use it with a wrong type (not comparable). The error message will be less than readable though. If you want a more readable message you need C++11 and static_assert.

Comment: (Contd) To see an example of such an error message, try using `struct foo{}; std::map<foo, int> a`. Demo http://ideone.com/PXL0x2

Comment: Things you can always do of course: Implement them as usual in a cpp file with an include of a specialization header at the end. This will require somebody who needs a new type for the vertices to change the specialization file in which you then simply put in detailed comments of what is allowed. Even with something broad as comparable objects, the amount of actually used specializations won't be *that* big and shouldn't require changes all the time.

Comment: I want to do this because my vertexes can have a broad range of possible properties. (i.e date of birth:date, age:int, name:string, lastlogin:dattime, ..) Most of my queries will only check for equality, and some for inequalities. The result for these comparisons should be true/false, thats actually all there is about these properties. Yes I've tried boost, but that isn't quite i'm looking for. @Aziuth Could you give a little more in dept example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not the actual answer but a requested example:

I'm used to create templates like that:

SomeClass.h:

```
#guards etc

template<class T> //or whatever you need
class SomeClass {

    public:
    SomeClass();
    T content();

    private:
    T m_content;
}
```

SomeClass.cpp:

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

template<class T>
SomeClass::SomeClass(){
    m_content = (T) 0;
}

template<class T>
T SomeClass::content(){
    return T;
}

#include "SomeClass_Specializations.h"
```

SomeClass_Specializations.h:

```
#guards etc

#include "SomeClass.h"

#include "MyMagicUint.h"

//only types that behave like unsigned int may be added!
template class SomeClass<unsigned short>;
template class SomeClass<unsigned int>;
template class SomeClass<unsigned long>;
template class SomeClass<MyMagicUint>;
```

If you do it like that, you can specialize a long list of some common comparable types and write a comment in which you describe what other people are allowed to add to that list (in my example, unsigned int like types for some reason).

As a result, only those which are specialized here will work (since otherwise the implementation is missing), you probably have covered most of them and in the rare cases that somebody needs another specialization, he simply adds it to the list.

In the end, doing is as strict as that might not be needed, since it won't compile anyway if some forbidden action is performed, like using the <-operator when it's not defined for that type, but if you want that strict control, you can do it like that. Of course this hasn't got the dynamic control of ? extends ..., but it has control at least. Another advantage is that you can implement the code in a CPP file as usual, instead of having to put everything in the header as required for a dynamic template, that's mostly why it is my standard.

You could of course simply write the content of the specialization file directly at the bottom of the CPP instead of including another header, but I think that the specialization header is more elegant, informing prospective users what is allowed and giving them the option to add to it without taking a look at the implementation.